# How to transform SQL "select case when in" to JPQL to get the same result?

Tags: java, jpql, jpa-2.0

My t_user table sample data is like

```
id   name
1    Hunt
2    James
3    Bob
4    Hero
```

And I use following SQL to get a boolean result, and it works fine as I expected.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN :userId IN (SELECT name FROM t_user) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS exist;
```

It returns following result if :userId is "Bob"

```
exist
1
```

Or it returns this if :userId is "Jack"

```
exist
0
```

However, when I transform that SQL to following JPQL (in which User is the Java class mapping of table t_user)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN :userId IN u.uid THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END FROM User u;
```

I get a result list like [false, false, true, false] if :userId is "Bob".
And get result list [false, false, false, false] if :userId is "Jack".
I think JPQL judges every row in t_user to match :userId and returns results respectively, but obviously it's not what I expect. I expect one single boolean result that's why I use IN clause.

So, anyone who can help to tell me what the right JPQL I should use here? Thank you so much!

Comment: Does it have to be a select? I would solve the problem with a simple query that returns something (either the user or a constant) if there is a user with the given id and nothing otherwise; then I would return true from the search method if there is a match and false if there is no match (zero rows returned). Wouldn't that work?

Comment: @ewramner, actually, I simplified the original SQL to current one, because the original SQL was too complicated to demonstrate my question.